# Pitch Bender for Roland Fantom FA-76

Tags: components

Any idea where I can get parts for Roland synthesizers?

I have a Roland Fantom (FA-76, the original without sequencers and what not) and its pitch bender seems to be a bit worn out, or possibly dusty. (As I pitch up/down, sometimes the pitching skips around a bit, especially near center.)  I'd like to get a replacement for the pitch bender, but can't figure out where to order parts.  E-mails to Roland never get replied.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but potentiometers' resistive elements often get a bit oxidised as they get older.

Generally, potentiometers are designed to be *self-wiping*, meaning that cycling the pot back and forth will often break through the oxide layer and restore some of the functionality.
Alternatively, any electronics [contact cleaner](http://www.google.com/search?q=contact+cleaner) may be very effective. Just squirt a bit down the sides into the pitch-bend controller, and work it back and forth repeatedly.

As a last ditch attempt, if the above does not work, the wiper may have relaxed a bit, and therefore may not be making good contact with the resistive element in the pot (see the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer) for info on how the internals fit together). It may be possible to disassemble the pitch-bend assembly and manually bend the wiper to help it make better contact.

I realize it may not be information on how to obtain replacement parts, but many companies are a nightmare to deal with regarding obtaining any information about the internals of their products, let-alone parts. It may be worth the time to try and fix the issue yourself before simply trying to replace the defective assembly en-masse.

Comment: Not a bad idea.  I didn't even consider this!  Perhaps I will tear into it this afternoon.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Although I'm eight years late, I'm having the exact same problem with FA-76. Did you try what Connor suggested after all, @Brad?

Comment: Ha!  Has it really been nearly 8 years that I've been putting off this project?  :-)  I was just thinking last night, as my pitch bender was acting up, that I really should take that thing apart this weekend and clean it up.